# ValueError:Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') even when isnan and isinf are false and dtype=float64

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, valueerror

My code is to analyze the **PUBG** dataset from kaggle and make a model. I have extracted all the features and **Standardised** them using **StandardScaler** from **sklearn**.

```
//Snippet

X=standardized_data
y=training_features_output
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.30,random_state=42)
print(standardized_data.shape,training_features_output.shape)
```

> [Output]: (4446966, 16) (4446966,)

```
print(np.all(np.isinf(standardized_data)))
print(np.all(np.isinf(training_features_output)))
print(np.all(np.isnan(standardized_data)))
print(np.all(np.isnan(training_features_output)))
```

> [Output]:
>  False 
>   False
>   False
>   False

```
print(X.dtype)
print(y.dtype)
```

> [Output]:
>  dtype('float64')
> dtype('float64')

```
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_train_pred=model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred=model.predict(X_test)
print('Train r2_accuracy:',r2_score(y_train,y_train_pred))
print('Test r2_accuracy:',r2_score(y_test,y_test_pred))
```

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
>   [error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnIFa.png)
>   [Full Code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O8I_I_TKyxGrO3ycAlQ6x_ztnYIqzB_b?usp=sharing)

From the above outputs we can see that they are no **nan** and **infinite** values in the dataset and also the data is in **float64**. but how am I getting this error and how to resolve it?
Tried other queries regarding this on stackoverflow all were having nan or something messed up and I dont know where is this code messing up.

Comment: `np.all(np.isinf(x))` <- you are not checking whether it contains an infinite/NaN value, you are checking whether you solely have them in the data.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have tried with np.any(np.isinf(a)) that results in False, and still having the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checking point **is not correct** because you are **checking if `all` the data are `inf`** using `np.all()`.

```
print(np.all(np.isinf(standardized_data)))
...
```

---

### **Instead, use `np.any()`.**

**Proof**:

```
a = [np.inf, 0, 1]

np.all(np.isinf(a))
#False

np.any(np.isinf(a))
#True
```